# MYSQL selecting DISTINCT value WHERE

Tags: mysql, json, autocomplete, distinct

Hi I have this problem I can't work out.

I'm using an autocomplete search to try to get a unique value out of a database table and I'm using the following statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT trackingChipNumber FROM `main` WHERE `trackingChipNumber` LIKE ?
----------
trackingChipNumber|Fate
----------------------------
DESTR2339442      |Relocated
FERW23445212      |Relocated
DESTR2339442      |Died
----------------------------
```

As you type it narrows the search of the records down. Currently it returns **DESTR2339442** and **FERW23445212**

What I need to do is remove any values where a Fate of Died has occurred.

The search should only return **FERW23445212** as **DESTR2339442** has since passed away.

I just can't work out how to do that.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is the same as @Ronny's answer. I also add some performance turning suggestion for your SQL. All my sql is verified on Mysql Community Server 5.6.48.

Please try the following SQL.

```
select
    distinct t1.trackingChipNumber
from main as t1 left join
    main as t2
on t2.trackingChipNumber = t1.trackingChipNumber and t2.fate in ('Died')
where t1.trackingChipNumber LIKE "%" and t2.fate is null
```

I'm not sure how you add index for this table and what the defination of this table too.
The following is the sql what I used to create this table:

```
create table `main` (
  `id` int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
  `trackingChipNumber` varchar(20) not null,
  `fate` varchar(10) not null,
  KEY `index_tcnum_fate` (`trackingChipNumber`, `fate`)) engine = InnoDB;
```

I'm not sure if this is suitable for your case, however, after adding such index, the query in my sandbox could be more fast. The coresponding execute plans are as following.

Before adding index, all data will be scan twice in `main` table.

```
mysql> explain select
    ->         distinct t1.trackingChipNumber
    ->     from main as t1 left join
    ->         main as t2
    ->     on t2.trackingChipNumber = t1.trackingChipNumber and t2.fate in ('Died')
    ->     where t1.trackingChipNumber LIKE "%" and t2.fate is null;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                                                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using temporary                                             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    3 | Using where; Not exists; Distinct; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After adding index, index will be used.

```
mysql> explain select
->         distinct t1.trackingChipNumber
->     from main as t1 left join
->         main as t2
->     on t2.trackingChipNumber = t1.trackingChipNumber and t2.fate in ('Died')
->     where t1.trackingChipNumber LIKE "%" and t2.fate is null;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys    | key              | key_len | ref                           | rows | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | index | index_tcnum_fate | index_tcnum_fate | 34      | NULL                          |    3 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary      |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref   | index_tcnum_fate | index_tcnum_fate | 22      | lzytest.t1.trackingChipNumber |    1 | Using where; Not exists; Using index; Distinct |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+------------------+------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks Zhiyong, Ronny's example fixed the issue and your answer was very helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.trackingChipNumber 
FROM `main` t1
left join `main` t2 on t2.trackingChipNumber = t1.trackingChipNumber and t2.fate = 'Died'
WHERE t2.fate is null and t1.trackingChipNumber LIKE ?
```